# How can I get the user location from gmail Contacts API?

Tags: java, gmail

I'm trying to get the location of a specific user from gmail contacts API. I am able to get the user name and other fields like last name, photo etc., but I am not getting location information of the user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't this Gmail contact api can give out such info. You might want to look into the [Google Latitude api](http://code.google.com/apis/latitude/v1/using_rest.html)

Or you mean his postal address?

That is available in the [gdStructuredPostalAddress](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/2.0/elements.html#gdStructuredPostalAddress) tag

Comment: but at the time of gmail registration we are provide only county information. so i think it only provide county location, i m not sure if i m wrong the please tell me. is that possible or not?